# I need to call data from one method to other method in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have one service file in that i have called two methods which are having two api's . i need to call getData method in deleteData . can any one help me in these

```html
.service.file
getData(): Promise<PagedResult<Sites>> {
    
    const url = `${environment.DATA_API_URL}/sites/GetSites`;
    console.log(url);
    return this.httpClient.get<PagedResult<Sites>>(url).toPromise().then((sites: PagedResult<Sites>) => {
      alert();
      console.log("sites: ",sites);
      });
  }

  deleteData(siteId: String): Observable<{}>{
      const url = `${environment.HELLO_API}/Data?siteId=`+ siteId;
      return this.httpClient.post(url, this.getSites)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('deletSites'))
      );
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  .ts file
  
  async ngOnInit(){
     
      
      this.sites = await this.dataService.getData();
      console.log(this.data)
       
    }
```

Comment: Have you used this return this.httpClient.post(url, this.getSites).map(res => you can call your method here);

Comment: at first look I can tell you that you don't understand how to use services. your service must return a promise and you must manage it in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Rannes I recomended you use Observable (pull apart Promise). then use Rxjs to concatenate, transform... observables. Therefore try to not "subscribe" in services

So, your service can be like

```
//return an observable
getData(): Observable<PagedResult<Sites>> {

    const url = `${environment.DATA_API_URL}/sites/GetSites`;
    //See that is a "simple" get
    return this.httpClient.get<PagedResult<Sites>>(url);
  }

  deleteData(siteId: String): Observable<{}>{
      const url = `${environment.HELLO_API}/Data?siteId=`+ siteId;
      return this.httpClient.post(url, this.getSites)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('deletSites'))
      );
  }
```

Well, Now you can "play" with observables in your component

```
   ngOnInit(){
      this.sites = this.dataService.getData().subscribe(sites=>{
               console.log(sites);
          })
      )
    }
    delete()
    {
      this.sites = this.dataService.deleteData().pipe(
           switchMap(res=>{
               //here you has the response to Delete,
               //but you want return the sites, so
               return this.dataService.getData()
            })
      ).subscribe(sites=>{
               console.log(sites);
      }
     }
```

Comment: this.sites = this.dataService.deleteData() here in this i need to get string siteId, and  also in ngOnInit this.sites it is not Obseravable because this.sites is a model which contain pageresults  i mean(sites:<Pageresult<Sites>>) here page result means showing multiple data which coming from API